# Which setting controls whether Windows Explorer will offer file/folder suggestions in Save As/Open dialogs?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

I was recently working on a machine that had a setting configured whereby when either entering text into the Run dialog or when within a "Save As" or "Open" dialog, entering any text into the "File Name" box would automatically populate the text box based on either files that had previously been opened, or files/folders that were located in the same directory; as an example, entering "C:\U" would pre-populate the text box so that the full path would read as "C:\Users". I can't seem to find which setting controls this behaviour, and would be grateful on any ideas as to how it can be enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 'Save as' or 'Open':

Go to Control Panel > File Explorer Options > View > and select either option of 'Automatically type into search box' or 'Select the typed item in the view'.  Another way is to go to > Control Panel > Internet Options > Advanced > Use Inline auto complete in File Explorer and Run dialog box.

For Run command:

A way to edit the commands that show up is to use the Run dialog, type in regedit and navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU.  This will show you a list of previously used commands that you can delete if desired.

Answer (score 1):

Go to registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoComplete.

AutoSuggest key controls the drop-down list will appear or not. Set it to "yes" to enable and "no" to disable.

Append Completion key controls the auto-completion of the names in the address bar. Set it to "yes" to enable and "no" to disable.